# get route in menu bootstrap react highlight

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

What to give an active class to a  NavItem in react-bootstrap with react-routes.

index.js

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Menu}>
        <Route path="explore" component={Explore}/>
        <Route path="whatever" component={App} />
        <Route path="*" component={App}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

menu.js

```
`<div>
<Nav bsStyle="tabs">
      <NavItem  href="/explore">Explore</NavItem>
      <NavItem  href="/whatever" active>TEST</NavItem>
      <NavItem >TEST </NavItem>
</Nav>
{this.props.children}
</div>`
```

Comment: have you tried using `IndexLink`?

Comment: Ist working with the react-router-bootstrap <LinkContainer/> as in the readme, no parent <Nav> tag possible. What about a collapsing nav in react-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

you can add links in react like the following code,
and if you want to add any style for it just put a className to each link

```
import { Link } from 'react-router'   
<Nav bsStyle="tabs">
      <Link To="/explore">Explore</Link>
      <Link To="/whatever" active>TEST</Link>
      <Link >TEST </Link>
</Nav>
```